# Is there a way to set a constant value in SQL for querying

Tags: sql

I want to check a series of field values in SQL, to save time and for future reading purpose, instead of writing

```
Select state from country 
where state in ('WV','DC','VA', 'MD')
```

I would like to write something like

```
states = ('WV','DC','VA', 'MD')
select state from country 
where state in states
```

But it doesn't seem like it works that way, how should I declare a constant value in a set of SQL codes?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?  Some DBMS might provide a way to do it; Standard SQL does not.

Comment: You would save the results in a table and use the table.

Comment: Please read the description of the SQL tag you added (hover your mouse over it). It strongly recommends that you also add a tag for the specific DBMS you're using, because functionality and syntax varies widely between them. Please [edit] your post to add that tag.

Comment: On a side note: The table should of course not be called country when it doesn't contain countries, but states.

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are working in SQL server, save your list of states in temp table #state_list and join it with country.

Select c.State
from country c inner join #state_list sl on c.state = sl.state

Answer (score 0):

The closest I can think of is a `WITH` clause combined with a `VALUES` clause:

```
with states(code) as ( values ('WV'), ('DC'), ('VA'), ('MD') )
select * from country
where state in (select code from states);
```

This is standard SQL, but not featured by all DBMS.